# Find the points on the surface (Z) where the tangent plane is parallel to the plane

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

> Find the points on the surface $ z =  \sqrt{x^2 + 4y^2 -4}$ where the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $2x + 2y + z = 5$

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know?

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Consider the parametrization $\varphi(x,y) = (x,y,\sqrt{x^{2} + 4y^{2} - 4})$, where $(x,y)\in D$ and

\begin{align*}
D := \{(u,v)\in\textbf{R}^{2}\mid u^{2} + 4v^{2} > 4 \}
\end{align*}
from whence you have that
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{x}(x,y) = \left(1,0,\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 4y^{2} - 4}}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad\varphi_{y}(x,y) = \left(0,1,\frac{4y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+4y^{2} - 4}}\right)
\end{align*}

then you solve $\varphi_{x}(x,y)\times\varphi_{y}(x,y) = \lambda(2,2,1)$. Can you take it from here?